How to send messages to users from a Telegram group using Telethon?
According to the Telethon documentation on entities, to send a message to a user with user_id, there must be something in common between the users, such as an active chat, shared group membership, or knowing the user's username.
The following function works only when the display of group members is not hidden:
participants = await client.get_participants('username')

Using participants, you can send messages to group members using user_id. But I don't have access to the list of group members because the admin has hidden it.
I can open a specific group chat in Telegram and access the messages exchanged in the group, including which user posted each message. How can I access the user entity from these messages and then send a message to that user using their user_id?
The following code doesn't work:
async def send_message_to_user(message_text):
    await client.start()
    dialogs = await client.get_dialogs(limit=None)
    async for message in client.iter_messages(dialogs[1].entity.id, limit=1000):
        await client.send_message(message.sender.id, message_text)

How can I modify this code to successfully send messages to users based on their messages in the group?
The problem is that in order to send a message in Telegram to a user with a user ID, we must get the user's entity in a certain way. As in the Telegram mobile application, you can select a user who has sent a message in a group and send a message to that person, I want to do this with the API.

message.sender is already the entire ´User´. You can remove .id. However, Telegram has very heavy restrictions on messaging a lot of participants and you will quickly hit limits.
